# Bluetooth keeps turning itself on after startup

Tags: bluetooth, thinkpad, 21.10

I have pretty stock Ubuntu 21.10 on my Thinkpad T440p. My issue is bluetooth keeps turning itself on after startup/reboot.

I've tried configuring TLP to disable bluetooth at startup, and to restore the state of bluetooth across reboots. Neither has any affect. I also tried setting AutoEnable=false in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf which also didn't do anything.

How do I make bluetooth restore to its previous state across reboots?

Comment: Do you want to disable Bluetooth entirely, or do you still need the option to enable it from time to time for specific uses? 

Comment: I'd still like to use it and enable/disable it from the GUI like normal.
@matigo

Answer (score 3):

There is a relatively obscure setting in the Blueman applet that will re-enable the Bluetooth radio when the system is powered on, be it due to a boot or a wake from sleep. You can change this in the Terminal like so:

```
gsettings set org.blueman.plugins.powermanager auto-power-on false
```

This should allow you to accomplish the goal of disabling Bluetooth and having the state persist across states.

Answer (score 2):

### Automatically DISABLING Bluetooth at Startup

Open the application called **Startup Applications**.

Next, click the "Add" button.

[image]

You can name it whatever you'd like. In the "command" field, add the following:

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

All this command does is turn bluetooth off. It doesn't kill any services or programs, except for turning bluetooth off. It is the same thing as turning it off via GUI. (In case you're wondering, running `rfkill unblock bluetooth` turns it back on.)

So after you type that in the Command field, press the Add button, and make sure the check box next to the new startup application is checked.

Now, when you boot your comptuer, it should be off at startup.

Comment: rfkill seems to work great. I do keep bluetooth off more time than actually using it so this is a decent solution. Thank you. However, if possible, I'd still like it to restore to the previous state.

Comment: @TheJooomes thanks. I'm currently finding a way to restore it to the previous state. I will edit my answer in a few days when I've completed

Comment: Works in 23.10. It's rediculous that such a switch can't be found in the settings where it should live.